# Font size of the headline

Tags: header-footer, fontsize, fancyhdr

I wrote a text in LaTeX with the font size as 12 pt. 
Now, when I create a headline the size is also 12pt.

How can I change only the size of the headline? I need a 10 pt size for headlines.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report} 
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,inner=3cm,outer=2cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}   
\usepackage[belowskip=-10pt,aboveskip=6pt]{caption} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhead[LO,LE]{\nouppercase\leftmark} 
\fancyhead[RO,RE]{\nouppercase\rightmark} 
%\fancyfoot[LO,LE]{\textsc{\uff}} 
%\fancyfoot[RO,RE]{\pet} %\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{\thepage} 
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt} \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
```

ps: sorry about the bad english

Comment: ok. Like o can see i´m new around here. sorry

Comment: sorry but when i press enter it begins a news post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}    
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,inner=3cm,outer=2cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[belowskip=-10pt,aboveskip=6pt]{caption} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhead[LO,LE]{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont\nouppercase\leftmark} 
\fancyhead[RO,RE]{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont\nouppercase\rightmark}
 %\fancyfoot[LO,LE]{\textsc{\uff}} %\fancyfoot[RO,RE]{\pet} %\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{\thepage} %\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt} \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
 \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Since you want the font size of 10pt, you may also use `\footnotesize` instead of `\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont` as noted by Enrico.

Comment: Harish Kumar what is the meaning of the 12 that you include on the fontsize?

Comment: Harish Kumar, your solution works fine. Thanks

Comment: @HarishKumar: Isn’t the _inter_ line space the space between the lines? I’d say the `12` give the baseline skip/the space between two baselines …

Comment: Sorry [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading) says inter line spacing is synonym …

Comment: You might want to say `\footnotesize` instead of `\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont`.